# Join columns from different files

Tags: r

I want to know how can we combine a specific column of one file with another column of another file in R?

I want to subtract 50 from the maximum of each column. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
a <- 50-max(datafile1$X2018.03.06,datafile1$X2017.07.13)
```

Comment: Didn't work how? What does your data look like?

Comment: Your code above subtracts the max of 2 columns from 50...NOT "subtract 50 from the maximum of each column" as your post requests.  Does `max(datafile1$X2018.03.06,datafile1$X2017.07.13) - 50` give you the expected results?  If not, please include some test data.